# How to get media URL with custom post api in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working and with wordpress API and when I fetch the normal posts, it returns all the details including the featured_image url. Here is a sample of the reponse

```
{
"id": 28923,
"date": "2024-03-04T11:23:17",
"date_gmt": "2024-03-04T10:23:17",
"guid": {
    "rendered": "https://searchmediamx.com/?p=28923"
},
"modified": "2024-03-04T11:23:17",
"modified_gmt": "2024-03-04T10:23:17",
"slug": "president-tinubu-signs-agreement-to-initiate-economic-ties-with-qatar",
"status": "publish",
"type": "post",
"link": "https://searchmediamx.com/2024/03/04/president-tinubu-signs-agreement-to-initiate-economic-ties-with-qatar/",
"title": {
    "rendered": "President Tinubu signs agreement to initiate economic ties with Qatar"
},
"content": {
    "rendered": "<p>President <strong>Bola Ahmed Tinubu</strong>, and His Highness, Sheikh <strong>Tamim bin Hamad</strong>, Emir of the State of Qatar have witnessed the signing of historic agreements between both nations.</p>\n<p>The agreements reached over the weekend are expected to pave the way for mutual cooperation in sectors such as education, enterprise development, investment promotion, youth empowerment, mining, tourism and sports.</p>\n<p>The Special Adviser to the President on Media and Publicity, <strong>Ajuri Ngelale</strong>, who announced the signing of the agreements on Sunday &#8211; said prior to the event, President <strong>Tinubu</strong> had assured his host of Nigeria’s preparedness to welcome investors into the country, noting the ongoing reforms that favour innovation, return on investments and multiculturalism.</p>\n<p>President <strong>Tinubu</strong> has since named the Coordinating Minister of the Economy and Minister of Finance, Mr. <strong>Wale Edun</strong> as the team leader of the government team that will interface with Qatari authorities in investment identification and implementation &#8211; moving forward.</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p><strong>In another scene, </strong></p>\n<p>The Federal Government has threatened to sanction foreign airlines that fail to comply with the directive to release low inventory tickets within weeks.</p>\n<p>The threat issued at the weekend follows a meeting between the Nigerian Civil Aviation Authority, Airline Operators, the NCAA, foreign airlines as well as the National Association of Nigeria Travel Agencies in Abuja last week.</p>\n<p>During the meeting, the foreign airlines pledged to enhance transparency in air ticketing processes by releasing low inventory tickets, making them significantly more affordable for the Nigerian middle class.</p>\n<p>However, findings reveal that not all the foreign airlines had complied with the directive.</p>\n<p>The Director of Public Affairs and Consumer Protection, NCAA, <strong>Michael Achimugu</strong>, told Newsmen on Sunday that defaulting airlines risked sanctions.</p>\n<p>A round-trip economy class ticket from Lagos to London with Air France costs N2.4 Million while for Lufthansa, it is priced at N1.9 Million. Qatar Airways offers the same ticket for slightly over N2 Million.</p>\n",
    "protected": false
},
"excerpt": {
    "rendered": "<p>President Bola Ahmed Tinubu, and His Highness, Sheikh Tamim bin Hamad, Emir of the State of Qatar have witnessed the signing of historic agreements between both nations. The agreements reached over the weekend are expected to pave the way for mutual cooperation in sectors such as education, enterprise development, investment promotion, youth empowerment, mining, tourism [&hellip;]</p>\n",
    "protected": false
},
"author": 20,
"featured_media": 28924,
"comment_status": "open",
"ping_status": "open",
"sticky": false,
"template": "",
"format": "standard",
"meta": {
    "_acf_changed": false,
    "_et_pb_use_builder": "",
    "_et_pb_old_content": "",
    "_et_gb_content_width": "",
    "jetpack_post_was_ever_published": false,
    "_jetpack_newsletter_access": "",
    "_jetpack_dont_email_post_to_subs": false,
    "_jetpack_newsletter_tier_id": 0,
    "footnotes": ""
},
"categories": [
    75,
    10
],
"tags": [
    404,
    405,
    403,
    406,
    366
],
"acf": [],
"jetpack_featured_media_url": "https://i0.wp.com/searchmediamx.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/president-Tinubu-signs-bilateral-agreements-with-Qatar.jpeg?fit=677%2C453&ssl=1",
"jetpack-related-posts": [],
"jetpack_sharing_enabled": true,

"_links": {
    "self": [
        {
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/28923"
        }
    ],
    "collection": [
        {
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
        }
    ],
    "about": [
        {
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
        }
    ],
    "author": [
        {
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/20"
        }
    ],
    "replies": [
        {
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=28923"
        }
    ],
    "version-history": [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/28923/revisions"
        }
    ],
    "predecessor-version": [
        {
            "id": 28925,
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/28923/revisions/28925"
        }
    ],
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/28924"
        }
    ],
    "wp:attachment": [
        {
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=28923"
        }
    ],
    "wp:term": [
        {
            "taxonomy": "category",
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=28923"
        },
        {
            "taxonomy": "post_tag",
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=28923"
        }
    ],
    "curies": [
        {
            "name": "wp",
            "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
            "templated": true
        }
    ]
}
```

}

As you can see above the "jetpack_featured_media_url" returns the featured image url.

But when working with a custom post, here is a same response

```
    {
    "id": 28819,
    "date": "2024-02-24T14:26:26",
    "date_gmt": "2024-02-24T13:26:26",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "https://searchmediamx.com/?post_type=advert&#038;p=28819"
    },
    "modified": "2024-02-24T15:20:56",
    "modified_gmt": "2024-02-24T14:20:56",
    "slug": "citardel",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "advert",
    "link": "https://searchmediamx.com/advert/citardel/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "citardel"
    },
    "featured_media": 28820,
    "template": "",
    "acf": {
        "promotional_text": "download handouts, past questions, textbooks from our cloud based digital library all for free. share with friends.",
        "link": "https://citardel.com/",
        "banner_image": 28820
    },
    "jetpack_sharing_enabled": true,
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/adverts/28819"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/adverts"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/advert"
            }
        ],
        "wp:featuredmedia": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/28820"
            }
        ],
        "wp:attachment": [
            {
                "href": "https://searchmediamx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=28819"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I get the featured image url directly in the api response?

Comment: Do you need the URL? Why not use the id `28820` from `"featured_media": 28820,` to pass to `wp_get_attachment_image_url()`? Checkout the [comments on this wp stackexchange question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323708/rest-api-get-featured-image-source-for-custom-post-type) - it's exactly what you're looking for.